# Neovim rplugin: why does vim.async_call(print, "msg") not echo?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-python, async

In a traditional `:python3` plugin, I can call `print("msg")` to echo a message.

In a [remote plugin](https://pynvim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/remote-plugins.html) function, I expect that calling `vim.async_call(print, "msg")` would do the same thing, but it does not. To be more concrete, in the following example, `:call EchoTest()` echos, and `:call PrintTest()` does not:

```
import pynvim
from pynvim.api.nvim import Nvim


@pynvim.plugin
class MyPlugin(object):
    def __init__(self, vim: Nvim) -> None:
        self.vim = vim

    @pynvim.function("EchoTest")
    def echo_test(self, _):
        self.vim.command(f'echo "this will be echoed as expected"')

    @pynvim.function("PrintTest")
    def print_test(self, _):
        self.vim.async_call(print, "this will not be echoed")
```

I understand that `Nvim.out_write` is probably the preferred way to do this, but I think I may be misunderstanding what `vim.async_call` does, and I would appreciate some clarity.